# I am adding data in RecyclerView but data is not getting reflected instantly

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add data in `Recycler View` but my  data extracted from `Edit Text` is not getting inserted instantly. Data is getting inserted only after I  do  some other operation like removing a list.
I have attached all of my codes in here .

I think `notifyDataSetChanged` is not getting called when i try to add a new text from edit text.

**Code:**

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sqlitedatabase;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Adapter adapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
TextView textView;
ImageView addTodo;
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
ConstraintLayout editTextContainer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<ListModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    editTextContainer = findViewById(R.id.constraintParentOfAddTodo);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    addTodo = findViewById(R.id.addTodo);
    addData(list);

    addTodo_onClickListener(list);

    adapter = new Adapter(this);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter.setList(list);


}

private void addTodo_onClickListener(ArrayList<ListModel> list) {
    addTodo.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        addTodo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.after_add_clicked, null, false);
        //Used for USERS input
        EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextTodo);
        //This ImageView is used as a button to set data in list
        ImageView setTodo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.sendTodo);
        Animation animAddTodo = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.righttoleft);
        view.setAnimation(animAddTodo);
        editTextContainer.addView(view);

        setTodo_onClickListener(editText, setTodo, list, view);

    });

}

private void setTodo_onClickListener(EditText editText, ImageView setTodo, ArrayList<ListModel> list, View view) {
    setTodo.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                String txt = editText.getText().toString();
                addToList(list, txt);
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                addTodo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
    );
}

//this function is Supposed to add new data to To do list
private void addToList(ArrayList<ListModel> list, String text) {
    //no work is done on id
    list.add(new ListModel(1, text, true));
}

//for displaying list initially
//this data gets inserted instantly
//No problem with them.
private void addData(ArrayList<ListModel> list) {
    list.add(new ListModel(1, "1", false));
    list.add(new ListModel(2, "2", false));
    list.add(new ListModel(3, "3", false));
    list.add(new ListModel(4, "4", false));
    list.add(new ListModel(5, "5", false));
    list.add(new ListModel(6, "6", false));
    list.add(new ListModel(7, "7", false));
    list.add(new ListModel(8, "8", false));
    list.add(new ListModel(9, "9", false));
    list.add(new ListModel(10, "10", false));

}
```

Adapter.java

```
package com.example.sqlitedatabase;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
private final Context context;
private ArrayList<ListModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

public Adapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_template, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.todoText.setText(list.get(position).getText());

    holder.notDoneBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (list.size() != 0) {

                    list.remove(list.get(position));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }
    );

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public void setList(ArrayList<ListModel> list) {
    this.list = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final TextView todoText;
    private final ImageView doneBtn;
    private final ImageView notDoneBtn;
    private  final RelativeLayout listBlock;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        listBlock=itemView.findViewById(R.id.listBlock);
        todoText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.todoText);
        doneBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.doneBtn);
        notDoneBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notDoneBtn);

    }
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TO-DO LIST"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </TextView>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout3"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="480dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.50">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        </ScrollView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintParentOfAddTodo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.794">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/addTodo"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="0dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/add_circle_48px"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.956"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </ImageView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

list_template.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:id="@+id/listBlock"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:elevation="200dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#932"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/todoText"
                android:layout_width="190dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxHeight="40dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Reading books"
                android:textColor="#EFEBE9"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold">

            </TextView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/notDoneBtn"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/todoText"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/todoText"
                android:background="#999999"
                android:src="@drawable/close_20px">
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/doneBtn"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/notDoneBtn"
                android:background="#999999"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/done_20px">

            </ImageView>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

after_add_clicked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/materialCardView"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:background="#121212"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:strokeColor="#888"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTodo"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="What to do"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="20sp">

        </EditText>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sendTodo"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_send_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.529"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/materialCardView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/close_20px"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/materialCardView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </ImageView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Screen shot of application]
This is how my app looks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're calling `addToList` to add your data, all that does is insert a new item into the list that your Activity and Adapter are sharing - the adapter has no idea anything's changed, so it won't update the display

You should be calling your `setList` function on the adapter instead - that replaces the current list with the new one (doesn't matter if it's actually the same list) and then calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` to display the "new" list.

It's always better to have a function like that on your adapter - when you have new data, you just pass it to the adapter, and it can handle the details of updating itself internally. The thing passing the data doesn't need to know anything about it. And if you want to update the way the adapter works later (say to be more specific about updating certain items, or to use a `DiffUtil`) then that's still an internal detail - the thing passing the data in just needs to pass the data in as usual.

(You should make `setList` make a copy of the list passed in though, like with `list.toList()` - if something modifies that original list, you don't want the adapter's internal list to change, that can lead to bugs. It's fine here, but if you used a `DiffUtil` for example, your `oldList` would also be your `newList`, and no differences means no update)

Comment: I added `adapter.setList(list)` inside `setTodo.setOnClickListener()`  and its working fine.

Comment: I would like to add one question related to layout, when i click on my editText view ,Keyboard will automatically cover my entire EditText maying user unable to see what they are typing. I tried using  `android:windowSoftInputMode` but it is still not working.

Comment: @roshannepal_x the default ``adjustUnspecified`` should work for ``windowSoftInputMode`` - you could try setting it to `adjustResize` if it's not making the right decision. So long as your layout isn't doing anything strange, and it *can* be resized, then it should just work. Otherwise I'm not sure, sorry - you should post another question (with the layout XML files) if you need help with it

Comment: I already had attached layout files In this Question.  `activity_main.xml` : this file  contains , a `recycler view` , a `constraint layout` below recycler view which I used for setting `EditText`  by using `inflate( )`, when `ImageView ` in `activity_main.xml` is clicked ` EditText` will appear.             `EditText` is present inside `after_add_clicked.xml` .          `list_template.xml` is used to inflate `Recycler view`